# Is max-height allowed on google responsive ads?

Tags: google-adsense, responsive-webdesign, google-adsense-policies

AdSense has a help page stating the acceptable modifications of ad code. [AdSense Document](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124)

One of the section speaks about specifying an **expandable** width and a **fixed** height. (The example given on the document has values for min-width, max-width and height.)

My question is, are we allowed to specifiy a **max-height** instead of **height**?

P.S. I want to modify a responsive **link unit** and not an text/display ad unit.